# How do I create a custom hash in which the key lookup is based on a function I define?

Tags: ruby, function, hash, key

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  How can I create a custom hash where the lookup function for the key is something I define?  I have this function ...

```
  def str_almost_equal(a, b)
    a.downcase == b.downcase || (a.size == b.size && a.downcase.chars.map.with_index{|c, i| c == b.downcase[i]}.count(false) == 1)
  end
```

and I would like my hash to lookup keys if both the classes of the keys are Strings and they match the method above.  So for instance, if I have

```
hash = []
hash["aaa"] = 1
```

Then I want hash["aab"] to return 1, because "aaa" and "aab" evaluate to true using the function I have defined.

Comment: What happens if in your example the key `"aab"` exists?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This might not the best answer, but I think it can help you

Use new class

```
class NewHash < Hash
  def [](key)
    if keys.include?(key)
      super
    else
      found = keys.find { |k| compare_almost(k, key) }
      self[found] if found
    end
  end

  private

  def compare_almost(a, b)
    a.downcase == b.downcase ||
      (a.size == b.size && a.downcase.chars.map.with_index{|c, i| c == b.downcase[i]}.count(false) == 1)
  end
end

hash = NewHash.new
hash['aaa'] = 1
p hash['aab'] # => 1
p hash['acs'] # => nil
```

Use module for each object

```
module CompareAlmost
  def [](key)
    if keys.include?(key)
      super
    else
      found = keys.find { |k| compare_almost(k, key) }
      self[found] if found
    end
  end

  private

  def compare_almost(a, b)
    a.downcase == b.downcase ||
      (a.size == b.size && a.downcase.chars.map.with_index{|c, i| c == b.downcase[i]}.count(false) == 1)
  end
end

hash = {'aaa' => 2}
hash.extend CompareAlmost
p hash['aab'] # => 2
```

replace origin Hash class

```
class Hash
  def [](key)
    if keys.include?(key)
      fetch key
    else
      found = keys.find { |k| compare_almost(k, key) }
      self[found] if found
    end
  end

  private

  def compare_almost(a, b)
    a.downcase == b.downcase ||
      (a.size == b.size && a.downcase.chars.map.with_index{|c, i| c == b.downcase[i]}.count(false) == 1)
  end
end

hash = { 'aaa' => 3 }
p hash['aab'] # => 3
```

Comment: Why do you have both "Hash" and "NewHash" classes?  Shouldn't I only need just your "NewHash" class?  I don't want to hcange the underlying functionality of all hashes, just create a new one with different functionality.

Comment: I just listed 3 solutions for you. So if you dont want to change `Hash`, just use `NewHash`.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own class inheriting from `Hash` and override the `[](key)` method to your liking. So e.g.

```
class MyHash < Hash
  def [](key)
    # do something to return the appropriate value
  end
end
```

Based on other methods of the Hash interface your calling code requires, you may need to override additional methods.

However, given your use case I doubt that you will be able to implement that method in a very efficient way as you would have to go through all candidates (at least those having the same length +-1) stored in the hash to evaluate whether they match. Of course, if there are not a lot of candidates in the hash, you might get away with it.

On top of that, I don't think that the behaviour of returning 1 when providing a key for lookup in a hash is a very hash like behaviour. I'd rather return the match. Returning 1 will violate the principle of least surprise IMO.

---

**Addition after OP's comment**

Without knowing your exact use case, so maybe I am off, I would sacrifice speed at insertion time and space for the sake of speed at lookup time. That means that I would precalculate all variants of a key at insertion time and insert those into the object used for storing.

```
class VariantsSet < Set 

  PLACEHOLDER = '_' # Use a character that will not be used in your keys

  def add_variants(string)
    merge(all_variants(string))
  end 

  def delete(string)
    all_variants(string).each { |variant| super(variant) }
  end

  def includes_any_variant?(string)
    all_variants(string).any? { |variant| include?(variant) }
  end

  private

  def all_variants(string)
    downcase_string = string.downcase
    string_length = string.length

    variants = [downcase_string]

    string_length.times do |i|
      variants << downcase_string[0, i] + PLACEHOLDER + downcase_string[i + 1 , string_length]
    end

    variants
  end
end
```

Usage would then be as follows:

```
2.4.2 :026 > s = VariantsSet.new
 => #<VariantsSet: {}> 
2.4.2 :027 > s.add_variants('foobar')
 => #<VariantsSet: {"foobar", "_oobar", "f_obar", "fo_bar", "foo_ar", "foob_r", "fooba_"}> 
2.4.2 :028 > s.includes_any_variant?('foobaz')
 => true 
2.4.2 :029 > s.includes_any_variant?('blubs')
 => false
```

Depending on the number of keys you want to store, this might require quite some RAM so if it gets out of hand, you might have to employ e.g. a database to store the values. But I would still recommend precalculating the variants.

The same can basically be done using a Hash as the superclass if that is more to your liking.

---

**Expanded to show hash implementation**

```
class VariantsHash < Hash

  PLACEHOLDER = '_' # Use a character that will not be used in your keys

  def []=(string, value)
    all_variants(string).each do |variant|
      super(variant, value)
    end
  end 

  def delete(string)
    all_variants(string).each do |variant|
      super(variant)
    end
  end 

  def [](string)
    match = all_variants(string).detect do |variant|
      super(variant)
    end

    super(match) if match
  end

  private

  def all_variants(string)
    downcase_string = string.downcase
    string_length = string.length

    variants = [downcase_string]

    string_length.times do |i|
      variants << downcase_string[0, i] + PLACEHOLDER + downcase_string[i + 1 , string_length]
    end

    variants
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm returning "1" because that's what's in my example.  If I ahd put in "55" then the example would have returned "55".  Anyway when you say "go through all candidates (at least those having the same length +-1) stored in the hash to evaluate whether they match", you're essentially restating my question.  I seek an answer to how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your expanded answer.  I'm a little slow when it omes to all this, so when you say "The same can basically be done using a Hash as the superclass", what methods am I overriding to make the hash lookup work in the way I describe?

Comment: I added the Hash implementation

Comment: thanks but this didn't quite work out.  If I set "hash["abc"] = 1" and then ran "hash["abb"]", I got back "ab".  However I should be getting "1" because per the function I listed in my question -- str_almost_equal("abc", "abb") evaluates to true.

Comment: @Natalia, I altered the `VariantsHash` to correctly return the value set for any of the variants. `hash["abb"]` will now return 1 as specified. Thanks for pointing out the bug.

Comment: Still a coupel of bumps.  Setting "hash["aab"] = 1" and then calling "hash["baa"]" produces 1 instead of nil.  Per my function, str_almost_equal, "aab" and "baa" would evaluate to false.  Is there anyway to incorporate my function into the custom hash?  That might simplify things.

Comment: Updated again @Natalia to include a placeholder so that your scenario is covered now. Incorporating your function would be possible but doing so would increase the time necessary to fetch an item from O(1) to O(n). One might be able to optimize this but it would never be as fast as accessing a hash is supposed to be.

Comment: Ok this is looking pretty good.  Setting 'hash["aaa"] = 1' returns "1" if I call " hash["aab"]".  The problem is if I run "hash.delete("aaa")" and then call 'hash["aab"]', it still returns 1, even though my hash is empty at this point, and should return nothing.

Comment: @Natalia fixed that problem

Answer (score 1):

For user created types Hash look-up uses two methods `#eql?` and `#hash`. This is the canonical way to override Hash behavior.

```
class StringWrapper
  attr_reader :string

  def initialize(string)
    @string = string
  end

  def eql?(other)
    string.downcase == other.string.downcase ||
    (string.size == other.string.size && 
     string.downcase.chars.map.with_index{|c, i| c == 
     other.string.downcase[i]}.count(false) == 1
    )
  end

  def hash
    # never actually do this part
    0
  end
end

hash = {}
hash[StringWrapper.new("aaa")] = 1
hash[StringWrapper.new("aab")] # => 1
```

But the reason to use Hash instead of other datatypes is that no matter how much data you have the time it takes to look up a key normally does not grow. But in our implementation above we've broken that. To see how let's look at how hashes work. Under the hood your data is being stored roughly like this<sup>1</sup>:

```
|0  |1  |2  |3  |4  |5  |6  |7  |8  |9  |10 |
|   |   |   |aaa|   |   |aad|   |   |   |aab|
|   |   |   |aae|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
```

When you look up a key in your hash Ruby doesn't compare it to all the keys that are already there. If it did that then look-up would get slower and slower the more keys you added. Instead it generates a hash for the key -- generally a big pseudo-random number. On my computer `"aaa".hash` returns 2707793439826082248 for example. `2707793439826082248 % 11` is `3` so it get's put in bucket number 3. Then when we need to look it up the process happens again and Ruby knows which bucket to check. Now instead of checking every key it only has to check those stored in bucked 3. Here is what we did when we defined `#hash` to always return 0.

```
|0  |1  |2  |3  |4  |5  |6  |7  |8  |9  |10 |
|aaa|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|aab|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|aac|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|aad|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
```

Every object gets stored in the same bucket so we've broken Hash look-up performance. When defining a custom hash method you need something that can that is the same every time you calculate it and appears random so the modulo operation spread your data evenly across the buckets. But the hash method must also respect your implementation of `#eql?`. If it doesn't you'll end up looking in the wrong bucket most of the time. For example if you wanted a hash that treated objects starting with the same letter as equal that would be easy.

```
 def hash
   string[0].hash
 end
```

The problem with what you're asking for is that one can construct a series of look-ups in which every string is equal to every other. "foo" === "boo". "boo" == "bao". "bao" == "bar". For the program to respect your definition of equality all of those strings would need to be in the same hash bucket. That means in order for your hash to behave the way you describe *every string* needs to have the same hash bucket. And that by definition isn't a true Hash. So I think you should step back and consider what problem it is you're trying to solve and whether or not a hash is really the right way to go.

You could certainly do what ulferts suggests at the cost of using more memory but what happens with

```
hash = { "aaa" => 1 }
hash["cab"] = 2
hash["aab"]
```

<sup>1</sup>: Ruby hashes with a small number of items are actually implemented as arrays, at least in MRI. These diagrams are hopefully helpful for explaining how hash tables work at a high level, not for actually showing how a given Ruby has implemented them. I'm sure there are any number of inaccuracies with them.

Comment: Despite the question asking for a "custom hash", this should be the correct answer, it is even documented on the Hash class itself:

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#class-Hash-label-Hash+Keys

The ruby-way to customize how Hashes decide if two objects refer to the same key is by overridden #eql? or #hash in the target object, not overridden the Hash itself, this is a "protocol" in the language intentionally create exactly for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what is your use case, specifically, what should happen if the key already exists. Assuming you only want to use your custom function to look up a value when the key does not exist, then it's just setting a custom default value to the hash. If that's the case, the solution is pretty simple:

```
## your custom function, changed to a Proc so it can be passed to a method
str_almost_equal = Proc.new do |a,b|
    a.downcase == b.downcase || (a.size == b.size && a.downcase.chars.map.with_index{|c, i| c == b.downcase[i]}.count(false) == 1)
  end

## iterator to run all values through your function
def check_all(a, array, func)
  array.each do |n|
    return n if func.call(a, n)
  end
end

## Hash with custom default value
h = Hash.new do |h,k| 
  if k.is_a? String
    key = check_all(k, h.keys, str_almost_equal) 
    h[key] if key
  end

h["aaa"]    ## nil
h["aaa"] = 3
h["aab"]    ## 3
h["bab"]    ## nil
h["aab"] = 4
h["aab"]    ## 4
```